# How to use input methods in minibuffer?

Tags: evil, minibuffer, input-method

I am writing some xelatex code with both English and Farsi (right to left direction) characters in it. Also I am using Emacs' input method (changing with key Ctrl + \) for changing between English and Farsi keyboards. It is great being able to use Emacs movement shortcuts and typing Farsi at the same time.

However I would like to be able to use Farsi input method in minibuffers, like the one opened by searching, too. The (Ctrl + \) key is not available there, and it is very inconvenient to have to change the system level input method two times whenever I want to type some Farsi character in some minibuffer (The whole point of Emacs' input method is to avoid scenarios like this).

So is this possible? If yes, I would like to know if it is possible to use Farsi characters with evil-mode commands (like f) or not. Thank you very much.

Comment: (Incremental search does not actually use the minibuffer - it just seems like it does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can toggle the input method in the minibuffer exactly like you can in any other buffer. However, as Drew points out in the comments, isearch *doesn't use the minibuffer* (it is actually just using the *echo area* to display information).

To *isearch* in a different input method you must enable the input method *before* you start searching.

Alternatively, if you have already entered isearch mode, you can type <kbd>M-e</kbd> to *edit the pattern in the minibuffer*, at which point you can toggle the input method with <kbd>C-\</kbd> as usual.

I don't use Evil, but chen bin confirms that it makes no difference (although the key bindings I've mentioned may be different under Evil).

Comment: evil has no difference

Comment: But how do you enable input method for _isearch_? This answer is marked as a solution but I can't find any way of toggling input method in minibuffer.

Comment: @lonelyelk, in the minibuffer you can toggle input methods using the normal key binding, but note Drew's comment on the question -- `isearch` *doesn't use the minibuffer*. So as I've said in this answer, you should toggle the input method *before* starting to isearch. *Or* (and for some reason I didn't suggest this the first time), start isearching, then type `M-e` to *edit the pattern in the minibuffer* (at which point you can toggle the input method).

Comment: @phils Oh! I see! So I would go `M-s w M-e C-\ wordinput RET` For a search. Thank you!