# How to terminate ambiguous multi-key input in input-method?

Tags: input-method

> *(I’ve titled this question as I have because I imagine the answer would apply to* any *input method that has multikey character inputs, such as `rfc1345`, not just `ipa-x-sampa`). If it turns out this is not the case, I’ll retitle the question before accepting an answer.*

I’m using the `ipa-x-sampa` input method for the first time—in the past I’ve usually used the `rfc1345` input method or `(insert-char)`, but right now I’m doing some phonetics-heavy work for which X-SAMPA is much-better suited. (For those who haven’t tried it: the `ipa-x-sampa` input method takes standard ASCII X-SAMPA input and inserts IPA characters.)

X-SAMPA uses postfix diacritics (e.g., “ë” is typed <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> or `e_"`) for characters that can also go alone (e.g., `e` which is... <kbd>e</kbd>). But it also has characters that have alternates expressed by non-diacritic postfixes. So for instance, “r” is `r`, but “ɹ” (the alveolar approximant, or “North American ‘r’”) is typed
<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> or `r\`.

Emacs shows the difference here in that when you type an <kbd>e</kbd>, it comes out right away and you’re back to typing the next character, but when you type <kbd>r</kbd>, the `r` is underlined (as in other input methods, that means “waiting for disambiguating input”) and the minibuffer shows the potential disambiguating keys. (This particular behavior of the minibuffer seems peculiar to `ipa-x-sampa`, as input methods that have dozens of potential legal following characters, like `rfc1345`, do not show potential completions. Or this may be a matter of some arbitrary limit or whether the list of legal following characters can fit in the minibuffer, I’m not sure.)

My question is this: if I type one of those and have the underline and minibuffer prompt, how do I say, “that's all, I just want an ‘r’”? <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> gives me `r` with the space, which I can delete. And <kbd>C-g</kbd> also terminates the r, but of course beeps and potentially cancels an operation in progress. So, is there a standard way in these input methods to say “I’m done with this character now”?

There aren’t many places where it matters—for the most part, X-SAMPA was designed such that it *should* be unambiguously convertible into IPA. But this isn’t 100% true.¹ For instance, the string `tS` can be rendered either as `t͡ʃ`(two characters, with a tie added separately) or as `ʧ` (one). In this case, I might have to type <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>C-g</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

It seems to me <kbd>C-g</kbd> *should* be right, as I know that `(keyboard-quit)` only cancels a single function—meaning if you’re in the midst of a function calling another interactive function, only the top-of-stack interactive is explicitly cancelled—but character continuation apparently doesn’t count; if I start an isearch with <kbd>C-s</kbd> and type <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>C-g</kbd>, the isearch is cancelled, so I only know of the <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd> working in this case.²

---

¹ X-SAMPA *is* more or less unambiguous in its most-common use cases of *phonemic* transcriptions and marked-language use. It only becomes ambiguous in close *phonetic* transcription and interlingual use.

This is why, for instance, in modern natural-sounding text-to-speech systems that accept X-SAMPA or IPA for pronunciation hints, even in places where you can write the X-SAMPA two different ways in IPA, both variants of the IPA will produce identical output speech, while in older, artificial-sounding, ones, the two would produce different speech—the older ones didn’t *have* to know what language they were speaking so could use “foreign” sounds, but the newer TTS systems always speak in a given language so “know” to substitute native sounds when necessary.

² [This answered question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/how-to-use-input-methods-in-minibuffer) notes that isearch does not actually “use the minibuffer” proper, and only uses the input method already set when invoked. This is true but, I think, irrelevant to my question.

Comment: The way some input methods handle this is by saying 'repetition == insertion', so in your case e.g. 'rr' => r, 'tt' => t. You'd have to extend ipa-x-sampa definition in ipa.el to get that behaviour.

Comment: @rpluim That’s good to know about some other input methods. Checking `rfc1345`, though, there are cases like this, such as `&ul` →  `┐` and `&ulR` →  `┮`, so it seems to be endemic to input methods that have variable key-sequence-length characters. Also, in `rfc1345`, every special character is introduced with `&`, but `&&` produces `&&`. And there are variable-length cases where the last character is a duplicate of the penultimate one.